# How to sign git commit using VC?

Tags: vc

I am just wondering how can VC can be used to sign commit using gpg, Currently I am using vc without sign mean I am using `vc-next-action` to perform git commit

Answer (score 2):

vc doesn't know anything about signing commits. magit does, though. If you're willing to have all your commits signed you can set `commit.gpgSign` in your git configuration file.

Comment: I'll use `commit.gpgSign` in git local configuration then. That solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Does it ask for passphrase? Mine is failing because there is not tty to ask for passphrase.

Comment: @Jangid, you should look through the existing questions on how to use gpg with emacs, I'm certain this has been answered before.

Comment: @rpluim, my gpg is working fine with emacs. I can encrypt files with .gpg extension, I can sign and encrypt emails. But only vc things are not working with gpg. As a workaround what I do is this. I run a pull request on cli, enter passphrase and because the ttl is set to about 10 mins, vc-next-action works without going into passphrase phase.

Comment: I get prompted by gpg-agent (admittedly a gui popup) when signing a commit. You should perhaps ask a separate question.

Comment: @rpluim, normally, when I encrypt/sign emails or open .gpg files I get a prompt in mini-buffer at the bottom. Because of `(setq epg-pinentry-mode 'loopback)`. But for vc, as you said, I get a prompt outside emacs. And on MacOS that is somewhat mangled so I cannot enter passphrase. Not Sure why I am not getting the prompt in the minibuffer like in the case of normal file encryption etc.